# How to add support to multi languages in android?

Tags: android

I would like to add support to different languages in my app. As I understand, Android uses the proper `strings.xml` file according to the operation languages of the device. But what If I want to allow users to change the language in the settings? What steps should I do? I thought of keeping the the user's language in the his document (Firebase cloud) but then if the user if logs out the app, the main page (login/sign up) will be in the default language (and not in his language).

I guess that there is a proper "flow" that I need to follow in order to add support to multi languages. Is it possible to share this flow with me?

Comment: [Localization](https://github.com/akexorcist/Localization) will help you. on signout clear language preference or set default language preference.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Just using the system language settings makes it much easier for both the users and the developers.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to `res`- `values`, then from the right click list create a new `Values Resource File`

from the window appears name the files strings and then select locale and add your language or country.. picture below to make it clear for you

[image]

then after that you can change the locale programmatically using these [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android) and let android system do the rest of work